# Newton Recursive Method for Square Root Problem in Python

Tags: python, recursion, sqrt

For a=13 and a precision epsilon=10^-7. How many times do you apply the newton recursion formula in newton_sqrt(13,10^-7)? Hint: use global variables.

My current newton_sqrt(a, epsilon) function is the following:

```
def newton_sqrt(a, epsilon):
     global count  
     if a < 0:  
         print("Error: a < 0") 
         return -1  
     elif a == 0.0:  
         return 0  
     else:  
         x = abs(a)  
         newx = 0.5*(x + a/x)  
         if abs(x - newx) > epsilon:  
              newton_sqrt(newx, epsilon)  
              count = count + 1  
              if not abs(x-newx) > epsilon:  
                   print (count)  
                   return newx  
newton_sqrt(13, 0.000001)
```

For whatever reason, I get

`918488688   None`

as my output.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no output since you never reach the print line:

basically, you have:

```
if x:
    if not x:
        print(something)
```

what you want, i'm guessing is:

```
if x:
    #do something
else:
    #do somthing else
```

not knowing the math of your function I would change it into:

```
def newton_sqrt(a, epsilon, count):
     if a < 0:  
         print("Error: a < 0") 
         return -1  
     elif a == 0.0:  
         return 0  
     else:  
         x = abs(a)  
         newx = 0.5*(x + a/x) 
         if abs(x - newx) > epsilon:  
              count = count + 1  
              newton_sqrt(newx, epsilon, count)  
         else:
              print (count)  
              return newx
```

which will give you:

```
newton_sqrt(13, 0.000001, 0)
23
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's be clear that your `newton_sqrt()` function doesn't work.  Either you're trying to instrument the recursion depth to fix it, or you're unaware it's broken.

A working `newton_sqrt()` would be along the lines of:

```
import sys

def newton_sqrt(a, epsilon, x=None):
    if a < 0:
        print("Error: a < 0", file=sys.stderr)
        return -1

    if a == 0:
        return 0

    if x is None:  # initial guess
        x = a

    new_x = (x + a / x) / 2  # refine guess

    if abs(new_x * new_x - a) < epsilon:  # test guess
        return new_x

    return newton_sqrt(a, epsilon, new_x)  # (better) guess again

print(newton_sqrt(13, 1e-06))
```

Once that's working, instrumenting the recursion depth using a global variable, `count`, is simple:

```
import sys

count = 0

def newton_sqrt(a, epsilon, x=None):
    global count

    count += 1

    if a < 0:
        print("Error: a < 0", file=sys.stderr)
        return -1

    if a == 0:
        return 0

    if x is None:  # initial guess
        x = a

    new_x = (x + a / x) / 2  # refine guess

    if abs(new_x * new_x - a) < epsilon:  # test guess
        return new_x

    return newton_sqrt(a, epsilon, new_x)  # (better) guess again

print(newton_sqrt(13, 1e-06), count)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
3.6055513629176015 5
>
```

Where `3.6055513629176015` is the square root of 13 and `5` is the recursion depth needed to compute it with an error of less than `1e-06`.